# Speedtest-CLI Cron Job Not Working

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, cron, crontab

Cron job is setup as:

```
*/15  * * * * speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log
```

The `speedtest` script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
speedtest-cli --csv >> /home/pi/speedtest.log
```

That uses Speedtest-CLI. The job is executing on time, but all I get is cron output that looks like:

```
Jul 19 08:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[29275]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 19 08:30:01 raspberrypi CRON[29378]: (pi) CMD (speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log)
Jul 19 08:30:01 raspberrypi CRON[29377]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 19 08:45:01 raspberrypi CRON[29430]: (pi) CMD (speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log)
Jul 19 08:45:01 raspberrypi CRON[29429]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 19 09:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[29608]: (pi) CMD (speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log)
Jul 19 09:00:01 raspberrypi CRON[29607]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 19 09:15:01 raspberrypi CRON[29791]: (pi) CMD (speedtest >> /home/pi/speedtest.log)
Jul 19 09:15:01 raspberrypi CRON[29790]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

But I don't see the speedtest.log getting updated. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that cron cannot locate the `speedtest` shell script. Try using a full path for this script in the cron job & see if that functions properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and as @Scot suggested you need to use the full path.

Get the full path with: `which speedtest-cli`. In my case this outputs `/usr/local/bin/speedtest-cli`.

Use that in your cronjob (or bash file):

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/speedtest-cli >> /home/pi/speedtest.log
```

*I found that in this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/n685tj/comment/gx5k27c/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3*